# Thingsboard No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, get, thingsboard

I am working on fetch data of thingsboard Restfull Http Apis using GET method, but we are not able to get fetch data.

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

We are calling Thingsboard Apis on Angularjs platform. How we can Solve this error.

**POST Method has been working fine, but we are getting error on GET method of thingsboard.**

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You need to remove check authenciate when request is `OPTIONS`

Comment: @TanDuong How we can Remove the authentication. Can you suggest how we can achive

Comment: You can check authentication for another request `'GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'` need required token. `OPTIONS` is request from browser. You can't add token to this. The only way you can reach is: Remove check authen in `OPTIONS` request in BE side

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? i am having the exact same issue, and if you solved it can you tell me how? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) request, because the API you want to use, has resources on a different domain.

Comment: hi, is there any solution to the problem asked? I was also on the same line